Android: How to make TextViews drag- and dropable?
I am writing an Android application where I display miscellaneous text snippets on the screen. The user should be able to grab/drag a snippet and drop it onto another snippet.
This works fine (i.e. the code and the misc. handlers obviously work!) but only if I define those text-snippets as EditText-elements. If I define them as TextView, then they do not react at all to the drag gesture.
The reason I want to use TextView over EditText here is, that with EditText the user can actually click into the text-snippet and start editing its content. This editing is not supported and has no meaning in my application. However, it could falsely lead the user to believe that he/she could adapt those snippets and I want to avoid/prevent that impression. Thus the content of these snippets needs to be fixed, i.e. non-editable.
I also tried using EditText-elements on which set I called <editText>.enabled(false); to make them non-editable, but oddly these then behave like TextViews, i.e. they can not be dragged and dropped anymore. :-(
So - it seems - that somehow the reaction to a click and start dragging gesture is interwoven with the ability to edit the text of that view.
Why is that so? Can that be changed? Can one have TextViews (or EditTexts that can not be modified) which are draggable?
